# C++/CLI: how to store a managed reference inside a native class?

Tags: c++, .net, logging, c++-cli, log4net

In my mixed solution (C++/.NET), I'd like to pass instances of Log4Net's ILog to C++ objects (to unify logging across the solution).

I thought to write a C++ interface (LogInterface), and then implement a managed-to-unmanaged adapter in a C++/CLI project, but the problem is that the unmanaged adapter won't be able to store a field pointing to the managed ILog instance.

Is there an elegant, safe and performing way to achieve this (other than storing the managed reference inside a static cache)?

```
class UnmanagedLogAdapter : 
    public LogInterface
{
    public:
        UnmanagedLogAdapter(log4net::ILog^ log);

        virtual bool IsInfoEnabled(void) const override
        {
            return m_log->IsInfoEnabled();
        }

        virtual void Info(const std::wstring& message) override
        {
            log4net::ILog^ log = m_log; // alternative that I want to avoid: log = StaticCache::Find(m_logId);
            log->Info(gcnew System::String(message.cstr()));
        }

    private:
        log4net::ILog^ m_log; //TODO: a managed field is forbidden
};
```

Comment: I realize it's 7 years later but I find myself thinking I need to do the same thing right now.  Did you end up doing this?  If so, how did it work out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `gcroot<ILog^>` member, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).